# Eclipse is showing every task in waiting state

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden my eclipse has stopped working. I have restarted it multiple time, i have even restarted my machine.

It is showing every task in "Waiting" state.

Has anyone has faced the same problem??

Thanks!
Pratik

Comment: Did you check your log file? Instructions on how to find it are at http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard steps in case of a "messed up" Eclipse: Try restarting Eclipse with `-clean`. If in vain, try deleting (make backup!) the entire `.metadata` folder of the associated workspace and restart. If still in vain, remove all 3rd party plugins you added to Eclipse afterwards, in almost all cases they are the cause of "buggy Eclipse behaviour".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching workspaces and then switching back? I had a similar issue that switching fixed it

Comment: Even that operation is coming in the waiting state :(